# Minting Token2022 token error. Account not found

Tags: token, token-2022

I am trying to mint a Token2022 token.

My first step:

```
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata
```

Then:

```
spl-token initialize-metadata EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu Snail SLUG https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples
```

Then when i try to mint tokens

```
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb mint EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu 100
```

im getting the error:

```
Error: "Account 5YFz2ASt6CYYvxBe9dfArEA7dciAdW7ADjZtyAgzam2C not found"
```

What is this account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution to this problem is that you first need to create a token account for your new token using the command:

spl-token create-account EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu

Then afterwards the mint will work.
Reason for that is that you first need a token account that you can mint your token into.